# How to create a php array for a form input field array such that the php array element should not contain blank values

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form consist of an input field degreename array. Now i am retrieving this array in php but the php variable create indexes for all input field array (`degreename[4]` and `degreename[5]`) even when `degreename[4]` and so on  does have no value. I want PHP array to have array element with values, there should be on blank value in PHP array.

Below is what I am trying. below is my html form code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="degreename1" name="degreename[]" placeholder="Degree Name / Diploma / School Std" >   
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="degreename1" name="degreename[]" placeholder="Degree Name / Diploma / School Std" >
```

I am retrieving this in a PHP file like below

```
$degreename = $_POST['degreename'];
```

The html form has only 3 degreenames with values and 2 are blank. I want PHP to create an array of 3 elements only.

Comment: you could loop the array and remove the blanks, or, when you actually use the array, check for blanks and ignore

Comment: i wanted a one step solution. have a look at Nick's answer, it works very smoothly.

Comment: convert it in to a checkbox so no need to do any PHP code at server side, only selected checkbox will appear in $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to process your input:

```
$degreename = array_filter($_POST['degreename']);
```

Output (for sample input of `array('MS', '', 'BS', 'MBBS', '')`):

```
Array ( 
  [0] => MS
  [2] => BS
  [3] => MBBS 
)
```

It will remove all blank entries while retaining the indexes of those that are set. If you also want to renumber the indexes, pass the result through [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) i.e.

```
$degreename = array_values(array_filter($_POST['degreename']));
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => MS
  [1] => BS
  [2] => MBBS 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kQg3A)